# Hover each row in nested grid from parent grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I would like to make a `hover` on each row from nested grid in grid which the template is rendered by columns instead of rows.

The structure looks like:

- Grid

  - Column

    - Column is display grid with only rows

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzsjhc8k/11/) with a structure. I did only hover on nested row. I know that I could reverse div structure, but cannot. I do have many dependencies on columns: resizing, drag and drops -> rendering it in row way would decrease my performances which I would rly avoid.

**EDIT**

When we hover on div element which is child of the `grid-wrapper__nested` I would like to hover **each** div on same row in each `grid-wrapper__nested`.

Vizualization:

[image: Effect]

Comment: Your question seems very confusing to me

Comment: I did add Image which is presenting what I would like to get after hovering on div without touching DOM structure

Comment: Can you try to rewrite your question? Even with the image I can't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, I will try in different way

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied with code in the question: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: @Pete Please have a look at the Edit section. I did explained wanted behavior

Comment: Please read my comment properly, your question is off topic - highlighting 2 words as code barely counts as a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you want to do is select the nth-child of each column. This can only be achieved using JavaScript, based on the structure you are using. You will also need to use a 'hover' class rather than a ':hover' state. In pure JS:

```
let table = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-wrapper')[0];
let columns = table.children;
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-wrapper__nested__row');

// Cycle throug each cell and add an event handler
for(let element of cells) {
  // Add mouseenter event handler
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    // Get index of cell
    let index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentNode.children, this);

    // Loop through each column and add 'hover' class
    for(let column of columns) {
      // Add hover class to nth-child
      column.children[index].classList.add('hover')
    }
  })

  // Add mouseout event handler
  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    for(let column of columns) {
      let cells = column.children;
      // Loop through each cell and remove hover class
      for(let cell of cells) {
        cell.classList.remove('hover');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzsjhc8k/23/)

If you are using a library like jQuery, it becomes even easier as you can use the jquery `on('hover', func)` function, in tandem with `index()` calls, etc.

Comment: I had hope there is a way without using JS, but yeah. That's perfect tho!

Comment: There are ways to do this without JS if you can structure your HTML differently (i.e. have the grid generate as a row and add the `:hover` state to the row). But as it is currently structured, JS is the only approach.

Comment: As I said, I have to many actions which depends on Columns and structuring it in different way would cause too many recalculations for too many div elements.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the way you "create" your squares. Now you write them out as columns. You need to change that so they are "printed" as rows. then add this to your ___nested section:

```
&:hover &__row{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

here https://jsfiddle.net/Lzsjhc8k/17/

Comment: What about hovering rows horizontally ? Now, we hover them vertically, can we reverse it ?

Comment: @yerpy Yes you can but then you have to restructure how you create your squares, the HTML structure.. Now they are "clustered" as columns. Sorry can't explain better right now...